# Creating A Simple Script to Resize Terminal and Open Zathura

Tags: scripts, vim, zathura

I'm writing my first script (I just moved over to ubuntu to get vim, vimtex, zathura, etc. to start editing TeX documents offline and I'm having to learn everything on the fly) and I would like it to do the following:

1. It should intake (as a variable if this is possible) a .tex file
2. alter the geometry of the current terminal window (so its flushed left on the screen and at the maximal height)
3. Open the .tex file in the current terminal in vim
   2 open the corresponding compiled .pdf file for the .tex file in Zathura and have the geometry of the Zathura window be flushed left and so that is fills the screen.

Essentially, the script should produce something like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/debhE.png).

What script would I need to do this? If it's even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a post about controlling window geometry [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43106/how-to-set-window-size-and-location-of-an-application-on-screen-via-command-line)

Short answer is, it's doable but the time you will spend writing and troubleshooting your script makes it an expensive proposition compared to snapping a window left and right on startup. There are keyboard shortcuts to do it, you don't have to use your mouse - [Super (Windows key for me) + Arrow Keys](https://vimeo.com/289091549)

Comment: Gee, those keyboard shortcuts are perfect! Thank you!